# How can I create 'conditional assets' for feature switches in rails when using the asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, conditional-statements, asset-pipeline, assets

I am implementing 'feature switches' so thaty admins can turn new features on and off using an admin web interface.

I'm able to easily do this in views with such such as

```
- if FeatureSwitch.where(name: 'display_demo_feature_switch_image', status: 'on').count > 0 
  # in reality would refactor that query to the controller/model. put here for clarity.
  %br
  %br
  %div{class: "onoffswitch"}
    %input{type: "checkbox", name: "onoffswitch", class: "onoffswitch-checkbox", id: "myonoffswitch"}
    %label{class: "onoffswitch-label", for: "myonoffswitch"}
      %span{class: "onoffswitch-inner"}
      %span{class: "onoffswitch-switch"}
```

But how can I do this in views when I am using the asset pipeline and make the assets be 'conditionally' included ?

So if I have a css asset manifest (`app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`) with:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require main
 *= require default
 *= require on_off_switch
 *= require jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css
*/
```

How can I make the `require on_off_switch` "conditional", depending on a true/false return from

```
FeatureSwitch
  .where(name: 'display_demo_feature_switch_image', status: 'on').count > 0
```

I tried renaming `application.css` to `application.css.erb` and using

```
<% if 'abc' == 'def' %> # While developing/testing
 *= require on_off_switch
<% end %>
```

but the assets always gets includes despite the fact that `'abc' == 'def'` is false...

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be creating two manifests, for example say on.css and off.css

In your controller add a before_filter with:

```
def my_before_filter_name
  @count = FeatureSwitch.where(name: 'display_demo_feature_switch_image', status: 'on').count
end
```

BTW, avoid using active record in your views.

In your layout:

```
- if @count > 0
  = stylesheet_link_tag 'on.css'
- else
  = stylesheet_link_tag 'off.css'
```

Note that you may need to test if @count exists.

If this solutions is not the best option for you case, you can use a content_for. In your layout yield :on_off and in your view add a content_for :on_off and test for @count to stylesheet_link_tag 'on_off_switch' (more details in [rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content-for-method))

Answer (score 0):

The solution seemed to be to just top put the conditional in

```
app/views/layout/application.html.haml #  (I use haml instead of erb)
```

i.e.

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
- if FeatureSwitch.where(name: 'display_demo_feature_switch_image', status: 'on').count > 0
  = stylesheet_link_tag 'on_off_switch'
```

but although that worked in development it didn't wortk in production and the stylesheet wouldn't be included.